Unbounded property of dual problem
I'm currently reading "AN INTRODUCTION TO LINEAR PROGRAMMING AND GAME THEORY" by Keough, and the author leaves the proof of the following corollary to the reader. Can anyone help me check my proof?
Corollary: If the objective function z of the max problem is not bounded above, the min problem has no feasible solutions.
Proof: Let the objective function $z$ of the max problem be unbounded above on the feasible region. Suppose to the contrary that the min problem has a feasible solution, say $\boldsymbol{y}_{0}$. Note that the feasible region of the max problem is non-empty by assumption, since if the feasible region is empty, then the range of $z$ is empty and therefore bounded. For each feasible solution $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}$ of the max problem, the weak duality property implies that $z=\boldsymbol{c}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}_{0} \leq \boldsymbol{b}\cdot \boldsymbol{y}_{0}$. Hence $z$ is bounded above, contradicting to our assumption.

It needs to be clearer that the max and min problem is talking about duality. i.e. the Primal and Dual. At face value, based on how you interpret “max problem” it could lead to the counter example
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max &z=x\\
s.t.& x\ge0
\end{array}
$$
which makes your claim false. Otherwise, you are correct if we’re on the same page about it being a Primal max and Dual min
